# How come a Desktop Environment be one layer under a shell (kernel-DE-shell instead kernel-shell-DE)?

Tags: shell, kernel, architecture, terminology

I ask the following question as a followup to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404250/gnome-shell-vs-unity) question.

How come a Desktop Environment be one layer under a shell (`kernel-DE-shell` instead `kernel-shell-DE`)?

### Why I ask this question

In Ubuntu, for example, both the [Gnome Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell) and [Unity GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)) for Gnome shell, are 2 layers above the Gnome Desktop Environment (DE), respectively.

### My assumption

Maybe the order is different between CLI-only and CLI+GUI systems, that is, maybe in CLI only systems it is, for example:

```
kernel-shell(sh,Bash)-utilities.
```

and in CLI+GUI system it is, for example:

```
kernel-primary shell(sh,Bash)-DE-secondary shell(Gnome shell)-GUI(Unity).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is *no* primary shell.

If you’re running the default GNOME 3 desktop, then the stack is

> Kernel → X.org or Wayland → GNOME session manager (which starts a number of GNOME helper applications) → GNOME Shell (which uses a number of GNOME libraries)

If you’re running Unity, then the stack is

> Kernel → X.org or Mir or Wayland → GNOME session manager → Unity (which also uses a number of GNOME libraries)

If you’re running a command-line shell in a virtual console or an old-school terminal, then the stack is

> Kernel → `login` → shell

A desktop environment is a whole set of applications working together to provide a consistent experience to the user. The “shell” is one of those applications (the one which acts as the last layer in the interface to the user, *i.e.* the one which has first dibs on user-initiated events such as keystrokes).

Comment: It looks like he was taking the execution chain for a stack.

Comment: Stephen, in `Kernel → X.org or Wayland → GNOME` r `Kernel → X.org or Wayland → Unity (shell)`, where does `sh` and `Bash` come in? I feel I miss that.

Comment: @Arcticooling they don’t. As I’ve said before, GUIs aren’t built on top of a CLI shell.

Comment: Hmm, so I should see both CLI shells and GUI shells as different intermediate "channels" of the kernel which are totally independent one of another.

Comment: Right, they’re independent ways of managing your system (managing files, running applications etc.). I’d tried to explain that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404170/86440) but perhaps not clearly enough.